# Adding root element and namespaces to all elements in an XML by using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

Can some one please help me in creating the XSLT for transforming the below given XML to the given required output which contains namespaces and a root element.

XML Input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Input>
<InputTypeItem>
    <BUC>AERNIG</BUC>
    <FromBUC/>
    <ADN>000000</ADN>
    <PO/>
</InputTypeItem>
<InputTypeItem>
    <BUC>A39DDZ</BUC>
    <FromBUC/>
    <ADN>000000</ADN>
    <PO/>
</InputTypeItem>
<InputTypeItem>
    <BUC>GGSAAE</BUC>
    <FromBUC/>
    <ADN>000000</ADN>
    <PO/>
</InputTypeItem>
```

Required XML Output (with namespaces):

```
<ns1:bucValMass xmlns:ns1="urn:valselTNS">
     <ns1:Input>
        <ns1:InputTypeItem>
           <ns1:BUC>AERNIG</ns1:BUC>
           <ns1:FromBUC/>
           <ns1:ADN>000000</ns1:ADN>
           <ns1:PO/>
        </ns1:InputTypeItem>
        <ns1:InputTypeItem>
           <ns1:BUC>A39DDZ</ns1:BUC>
           <ns1:FromBUC/>
           <ns1:ADN>000000</ns1:ADN>
           <ns1:PO/>
        </ns1:InputTypeItem>
        <ns1:InputTypeItem>
           <ns1:BUC>GGSAAE</ns1:BUC>
           <ns1:FromBUC/>
           <ns1:ADN>000000</ns1:ADN>
           <ns1:PO/>
        </ns1:InputTypeItem>
</ns1:Input>
  </ns1:bucValMass>
```

Answer (score 2):

It essentially needs a single template rule:

```
<xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:element name="ns1:{local-name()}" namespace="urn:valselTN">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Plus another to add the root element:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <ns1:bucValMass xmlns:ns1="urn:valselTNS">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </ns1:bucValMass>
</xsl:template>
```